# Safari crashes when using Rails inline_svg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, inline-svg

Certain pages in my Rails app seem to crash Safari complete when there are svgs on the page using the `inline_svg` gem.

Navigating to the page results in the error message 'Safari Web Content quit unexpectedly.'

Here is the part of the stack trace that leads me to believe it is an issue with SVG rendering:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e2c1286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9a58db53 abort + 129
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff9a555c39 __assert_rtn + 321
3   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff90ff9d0e CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath + 242
4   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff9101de10 CGContextAddPath + 93
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff920d70c0 WebCore::GraphicsContext::strokePath(WebCore::Path const&) + 80
6   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff929c4140 WebCore::RenderSVGShape::strokeShape(WebCore::GraphicsContext*) const + 160
7   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff929c8673 WebCore::RenderSVGPath::strokeShape(WebCore::GraphicsContext*) const + 99
8   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff929d0fce WebCore::RenderSVGShape::strokeShape(WebCore::RenderStyle const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*) + 126
9   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff929d116f WebCore::RenderSVGShape::strokeShape(WebCore::GraphicsContext*) + 191
10  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff929d11ce WebCore::RenderSVGShape::fillStrokeMarkers(WebCore::PaintInfo&) + 78
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff91ff927b WebCore::RenderSVGShape::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 379
12  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff92052b03 WebCore::RenderSVGContainer::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 531
13  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff92052b03 WebCore::RenderSVGContainer::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 531
14  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff92052b03 WebCore::RenderSVGContainer::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 531
15  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff91ff8f12 WebCore::RenderSVGRoot::paintReplaced(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 1330
16  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff91f70d32 WebCore::RenderReplaced::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 722
```

Here is what the svg itself looks like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns" width="91px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 91 25" version="1.1" class="priority-urgent">
    <title>Urgent</title>
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="1/18" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
        <g id="Detail" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-459.000000, -264.000000)">
            <g id="Group" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" transform="translate(429.000000, 103.000000)">
                <g id="Urgent_flag" transform="translate(30.000000, 161.000000)">
                    <rect id="Rectangle-28" fill="#E74C3C" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="0" y="0" width="91" height="25" rx="2">    </rect>
                    <text id="URGENT" sketch:type="MSTextLayer" font-family="Gotham Book" font-size="16" font-weight="313" sketch:alignment="middle" line-spacing="19" fill="#FFFFFF">
                        <tspan x="10.508" y="18">URGENT</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was an issue with the `padding` I had applied to the css class I had on the `<svg>`. Something maybe with Safari taking padding into account for how large or small the image should be scaled possibly? Anyway, after removing the padding, Safari stopped crashing.